# Throwing errors with stopping the flow in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

I have a very simple flow: One inject node, and two function nodes.
In the first function I have the following code:

```
node.error("test",msg);
return msg;
```

And in the second:

```
node.warn("this shouldn't be printed");
return msg;
```

The [documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-js#handling-errors) says:

> If the node encounters an error that should halt the current flow, it should log the event with the `this.error` function.

But both messages show up on the debug panel from the GUI of node-red, meaning the flow does not halt.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is about creating custom nodes, and it is an instruction to the author about what they need to do in the situation of an error, not what the platform will do for you.

Those instructions don't really apply to code you write in a function node, but if you were to follow them you would need to remove the `return msg;` from the function for the error case.

In reality you would use a test to decide if you would call `node.send(msg);` in the custom node or `return msg;` in the function node.